# detect if contact has photo

Tags: android, file, uri, photo, exists

I've got an ImageView which I'm displaying a contacts picture using a Uri which always looks similar to this:

> content://com.android.contacts/contacts/34/photo

How would I be able to detect whether this photo exists, as if it doesn't then I want to use a placeholder instead (stored in my drawable folder). At the moment it just shows a blank image.

Comment: I have the same problem, I get the URI of the photo, but it might not exist on the file system (like when you take out the SD Card)

Comment: have u figured this out yet? im still stuck

Answer (score 9, accepted):

a function to get a contacts photo uri:

```
public Uri getPhotoUri(Integer contactid) {
    Cursor photoCur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '1'", null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME+" COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
    photoCur.moveToPosition(contactid);
    Uri person = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, photoCur.getLong(photoCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)));
    Uri photo = Uri.withAppendedPath(person, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
    return photo;
}
```

and calling that function (contactimage is an ImageView):

```
Uri contactphoto = getPhotoUri(2);
contactimage.setImageURI(contactphoto);
if (contactimage.getDrawable() == null) {
    contactimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.contactplaceholder);
}
```

Comment: please tell me how to get this no.(2),  getPhotoUri(2); your code works for me

Answer (score 6):

Possibly by using `ContactsContract.Data.PHOTO_ID`. If it doesn't have a value, then there is no photo.

Comment: thanks but ive allready figured out a workaround. will post it up when i get a chance

Comment: Please do, I'm interested in seeing what you did.